# Can I make Starcraft 2 portable?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I were to install Starcraft 2 in a external hard drive (changing the install folder during installation), could I run it on another computer without installing? For example, if I installed starcraft 2 on a usb, and then plugged the usb into ANOTHER computer, would it run properly? I'm fine with just offline single player mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I'm inclined to say it is (having played both Starcraft II and Diablo III off of an external hard drive in the past), but... do you have a large enough USB drive?

My Starcraft II folder is currently sitting at 13.5 gigs. If you can get all of that onto the flash drive, you should be good to go.

Comment: You can get 16/32GB USB sticks pretty cheaply these days. Also, I can confirm that copying the /Starcraft II folder to a different computer is perfectly fine, I daresay running it off a USB stick will be as well (apart from slow load times)

Comment: I would recommend an exertal SSD for gaming puposes - they are still pretty cheap. And yes. Blizzard games can be moved around as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

In one of the past Intel Extreme Masters tournaments, each player was given an SSD so that they could fully customize everything (settings, OS, etc.  For every match, they would just pop that SSD into which ever computer they needed to play on.  You could do the same but with an external SSD like @AtlasEU suggested.

Comment: They may have had a full OS installed on the drive, or configured it so that it would work on their otherwise tightly controlled hardware.

Comment: True, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Starcraft 2 should run just fine if you just copy its folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just copy the folder and it will run fine. Just be aware the configuration file which contains audio / graphics will remain the ones you had when installed.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you just copy the folder, but you can't update.